# How To Use "{0}" In A File.WriteAllLines?

Tags: c#, io, writealltext

So, I am attempting to create multiple files with different names. I am trying to change one number in the file name like this, but it won't let me use "{0}" to insert a string.

```
String value = "1";

foreach (var message in reddit.User.PrivateMessages) {
  var pm = message as PrivateMessage;

  File.WriteAllText(
    (@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{0}.txt", value), 
    pm.Body);
}
```

The main point is I want to be able to create multiple files with a foreach loop. I can handle the int parsing seperately.

Comment: Use more variables: `string path = ...;`  Now it will be obvious what you did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want *formatting* (`String.Format`):

```
File.WriteAllText(
   String.Format(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{0}.txt", value),
   pm.Body);
```

In *C#6.0* you may put it as *string interpolation*:

```
File.WriteAllText(
   $@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{value}.txt",
   pm.Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `File.WriteAllText`.

Try this using `string.format`

```
 File.WriteAllText(string.format(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{0}.txt", value), pm.Body);
```

or using c# 6.0 like this

```
File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{value}.txt", pm.Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code is broken currently; you left out `string.Format(`:

```
File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Programming\test{0}.txt", value), pm.Body);
```